# Any reason NOT to upgrade to VS2010? (Besides the cash of course!)

Tags: visual-studio

For those with experience of VS2008 and VS2010.  Are there any areas in which you prefered 2008?  Any annoyances with the upgrade?

Any reasons not to upgrade?

I'm coming at this from a Web Dev point of view.

Thanks

Comment: The source of my fear is largely an upgrade I did in the past:  Office2003>>Office2007.  Man, was THAT a mistake!  Slow as hell, and I still can't figure out half of what I want to do.  Suddenly my computer-literacy dropped to my grandma's level.

Comment: I've been using 2010 since the beta and I can't think of any way in which my development experience has been hindered. The UI is still the same, except better. Plug-ins need updates of course, but actively developed plug-ins already have updated VS2010 versions out.

Comment: @sander - thanks, that is reassuring!

Comment: After 3 years you still can't figure out the Ribbon? And you're putting production software into the world? Eek.

Comment: @John - Thanks for the snide remark! We need more people like you in on Stack Overflow.  You must be very clever.

Comment: If you want to tell the world you're not able to use one of the world's most popular applications, I think you can expect some ribbing. Get a sense of humour or don't post such things.

Comment: @john - I think you may be confusing being funny with being a jerk!

Comment: Sheesh, some people really take themselves too seriously. In the grand scheme of things, it's really not important that you can't figure out how to use MS Word.

Comment: @John: Please find some other post to troll on.

Comment: You really came back 2 weeks later to say that? It must really be important to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depend principally of how you use VS.

If your goal is to continue to use Windows Form without Linq (some people stay with VB6...), VS 2010 don't seems to be a good investment...

But if you use, or plan to use WPF and co., VS 2010 seems to be a good investment for me !

So, i think it's interesting to ask yourself : "Any reason NOT to upgrade to WPF and Linq ?"

About your the fear of change like Office 2003 -> Office 2007

Yes, me too, i feel "dropped to my grandma's level"...

But i feel like that too with the change Windows Form -> WPF.

It's good for me : it's not with the improvement of the candle the the bulb was invented !

Office 2007 is for me a great improvement for the user interface...
But it's just my point of vue.

Comment: Ok thanks, but I'm really interested if there are reasons NOT to upgrade (there are plently of reasources listing the new features).  Regarding your points: I will be doing very little windows forms application development, and so WPF is not really a priority for me.  Linq is very important though.

Comment: Glad you finally found Office 2007 productive :)

Comment: If you stay just with little Windows Forms application, I don't think you take advantage of an upgrade to VS 2010.

Link is a point to evaluate, but, for little development, why don't use the free express edition of VS ?

Comment: Yes, with Office 2007, I have "discover again" functionality i never use with 2003 because they was not easily accessible on the UI. And, when you pass through the difficulty of the change, it was a real pleasure to use. All the users of my society have the same experience and feeling about that.

Comment: (please excuse my English : it's not my native language, i learn it just 2 years ago)

Comment: @Service Informatique - Just to clarify, I won't be doing much Windows Forms work, but will be doing a lot of Web based work.  By the way- Your English is much better than my French :)

Answer (score 1):

The main reason to upgrade to Visual Studio 2010 is the .NET Framework's new version 4.0, and all the accompanying tools you can use.

If you don't need this new version now, you can **delay** the upgrade: that's a reason.

But sooner or later, because we all know that we can't stay behind, we'll have to step forward... This is why all of us are using Visual Studio 2008 instead of Visual Studio 6.0 and build software for Windows 7 instead of Windows 98...

Comment: Yes, I would like to upgrade, but my motivation is weak enough that I might not do so at the moment if there are also going to be things I don't like.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in a team, one person upgrading forces all of your developers to have to upgrade as the Solution files and Project files will be marked as being 2010 format and VS2008 won't read them. One of our developers checked in a project using a 2010 beta and now we can't work on it as we didn't buy 2010 yet :(

Comment: Can't you reimport all the files into a new VS2008 project? And get the 2010 Express version to find those settings you need?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you get VS2010 Express (when it's around) and experiment with it as far as performance goes. It's not quite the same as the full version, but close enough to spot big problems I should think.